# How to use multiple axios header

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, axios, fetch

I'm devolopping react-native app. 
    This project use FatSecret REST API. 
    This api use Authentication with OAuth 2.0. 
    First of all, i receive Access Token.
    I tried to receive data using a token and got an error.
    Sending a post gives me a status code of 200, but I don't understand.

```
    let form = new FormData();

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("content-type", "application/json"),
      headers.append(
        "Authorization",
        "Basic " +
          base64.encode(
            <clientID>:<clientSecret>,
          ),
      ),
      form.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    form.append("scope", "basic");

    fetch("https://oauth.fatsecret.com/connect/token", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: form,
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json =>{this.calc(json.access_token)})


  };

//------------------------------------------------------
//success (get Access token)
//--------------------------------------------------------

  calc =(token)=>{  
    console.log(token)

    var headers2 = new Headers();
    headers2.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers2.append(
      "Authorization",
      "Bearer "+token),

    fetch("https://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api",{
      method :"POST",
      headers:headers2,
      body:"method=foods.search&search_expression=toast&format=xml"
    }).then(res=>console.log(res));
}

Response {type: "default", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: undefined, headers: Headers, …}
headers: Headers {map: {…}}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: undefined
type: "default"
url: "https://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api"
_bodyBlob: Blob {_data: {…}}
_bodyInit: Blob {_data: {…}}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What is the error you get and where in the code you provided did you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for multiple headers with axios:

```
const instance = axios.create();
      instance.defaults.headers.common['Accesstoken'] = 'Bearer '+token;

      const response = await instance.post(<api url>, {
        id: orderId
      });
```